# Spin Representations

Tags: representation-theory, mathematical-physics

In the book Gauge Fields, Knots and Gravity, spin "j" representation is described as homomorphisms from SU(2) to the General linear group of space of polynomials of degree $2j$ in $\mathbb{C}$ in one specific way namely  $(\rho(g)f)(v)=f({g}^{-1}(v))$, Here $v=(x,y)$ is an element of $\mathbb{C}^2$, $f$ is a degree $2j$ polynomial and $g$ is an element of $SU(2)$.

On Wikipedia spin group is defined as follows.

The spin group $Spin(n)$ is the double cover of the special orthogonal group $SO(n) = SO(n, R)$, such that there exists a short exact sequence of Lie groups (when $n \neq 2$).

$ {1} \rightarrow Z_2 \rightarrow Spin(n) \rightarrow SO(n) \rightarrow 1 $

Could someone describe how these two definitions are related?

Thanks

Comment: The relationship is that $SU(2)$ is isomorphic to $Spin(3)$. This is by no means obvious, but see for example: https://qchu.wordpress.com/2011/02/05/so3-and-su2/